# OpenSSH: X-Forwarding: wrong authorisation protocol

Tags: xorg, openssh

I have edited the /etc/ssh/sshd_config so that:

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalHost no
```

And I connect to the host with: ssh -X

Yet, when I try to open firefox for example I get:

```
GLib-CRITICIAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted
PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted
Error: cannot open display: <ip>:10.0
```

I connect using a windows 8 host that is running an Xming server and putty.
I tried connecting using a linux host (Ubuntu) but that gives the following error:

```
GLib-CRITICIAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication
```

Using `echo $DISPLAY` when inside the connected host does give me a display.
And `xauth list` shows my magic-cookie.

Comment: `/etc/sshd_config` or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? X11 Forwarding is enabled by default unless you disable it.

Comment: /etc/ssh/sshd_config indeed. Ah, X11 was commented in my config file.

Comment: It was? The default `sshd_config` has `X11Forwarding yes` and `X11DisplayOffset 10` - which OS are you using? Also: spelling error in `AllowTcpForwarindg`.

Comment: Ah, I built my own SSH version with some edits. And that probably did not create a default config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer.

Make sure the following is set to yes:

```
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Make sure /etc/hosts contains the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```